# IE11: Ternary in javascript "sort" throws a syntax error

Tags: javascript, sorting, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ternary-operator

I have what I assumed to be a simple sort function,

```
data.sort((a, b) => (b.alreadyExists) ? 1 : -1);
```

This works fine in Chrome and JSFiddle in chrome, but not IE11: am I doing something wrong, or is this just one of those annoying IE11 things?

Unfortunately "Don't use IE11" isn't an option here :(

Comment: Don't use arrow function in IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Or use [`Babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile it to compatible version  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). In IE 11, you could write the function like this:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.alreadyExists ? 1 : -1;
});
```